# Is this set a contradiction or just confusing?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Book says "Prove that:$$A\cap B^c\subset B\Leftrightarrow A\subset B"$$

But if $A\subset B $ then $A\cap B^c=\emptyset$ isn't it?
is book wrong?

Comment: Well, if that's the case, what's the contradiction?

Comment: Ask yourself if $\emptyset\subset B$.

Comment: Oop,s the contradiction i was trying to expose is that if $a\in A \land a\notin B$, but if $a\in A, a\in B$

Comment: If i wanted to prove "$\Leftarrow$", I would have t ouse the fact "$a\in A \land a\notin B \Rightarrow a\in B$", which somehow doens't make sense for me...

Comment: If $A \subset B$, then $A \cap B^c= \emptyset \subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\cap B^c\subseteq B$. Suppose there's a $b\in A\cap B^c$, then $b\in A$ and $b\not\in B$, but from hypothesis, we have that $b\in B$, a contradiction, thus $A\cap B^c$ is empty.

Now, the set $A\cap B^c$ consists of all the elements that are in $A$ and in $B^c$, this means that (as the intersection is empty), if $a$ is $A$, then $a$ **is not in** $B^c$, that is, $a\in B$.

Comment: Thanks again, did u change from $b$ to $a$ in your reasoning?

Comment: @JoséOsorio Yes, sorry! It's fixed now.